# Is a tensor product of subquotients a subquotient of the tensor product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a rigid abelian tensor category, and $M$ an object of $\mathcal{C}$.

We denote by $\langle M \rangle$ the full, abelian subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ closed under subquotients generated by $M$. Here there is no problem: its objects are all subquotients of finite direct sums of copies of $M$. This works because direct sums of subquotients are subquotients of direct sums, so that we get all the objects that we wanted.

We denote by $\langle M \rangle ^{\otimes,\vee}$ the full, abelian, rigid tensor subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ closed under subquotients generated by $M$. Here it is harder to say exactly what the objects are. Here is what I would like:

> Its objects are all subquotients of finite direct sums of finite tensor products of copies of $M$ and $M^\vee$. In other words, its objects are all subquotients of ''polynomial objects'' in $\mathbb{N}[M,M^\vee]$, where multiplication corresponds to tensor product and addition to direct sum.

The problem is that I am not sure whether tensor products of subquotients are subquotients of tensor products. Given maps $f_i: A_i \to B_i$ ($i =1,\dots,n$), we have a map
$$\otimes f_i: \otimes A_i \to \otimes B_i.$$
But even if all the $f_i$ are injective or surjective, I do not know whether $\otimes f_i$ is, right? Already for modules, injectivity fails in general... So we do not get subquotients. Am I missing something? Or do I really have to change the statement? And if I write

> Its objects are all subquotients of finite direct sums of finite tensor products of **subquotients of** $M$ and $M^\vee$

instead, does it get any better? I fear that then I end up in an endless loop of

> subquotients of finite direct sums of finite tensor products of subquotients of finite direct sums of finite tensor products of subquotients of finite direct sums of finite tensor products of ... of subquotients of finite direct sums of finite tensor products of subquotients of $M$ and $M^\vee$.

Is there really no compact description of the objects of this category?